# Lower bound the ratio of the combinatorial quantities

Tags: co.combinatorics, inequalities

Suppose $p < q$, $s = p^{d}$ for some fixed $d \in (0,1)$, let $p$ goes to infinity, define the following quantity,
\begin{aligned}
\quad f(j) = \sum_{i = 0}^{\min(j,s)}{s \choose i}{p-s \choose i}{s \choose j-i}{q-s \choose j-i}
\end{aligned}
How to lower bound $\frac{f(j+1)}{f(j)}$? That is
\begin{aligned}
   \frac{f(j+1)}{f(j)} \geq \;?
\end{aligned}

Comment: Does this quantity have a combinatorial interpretation? Sometimes it is easier to work with that than with the formula.